# Is it ok to make backend call using reducer in redux?

Tags: redux

I'm building an angular website. Normally I made backend call in onInit method and store the data in an component state. Now I want to add redux to my website. Should I just raise action on the onInit method and make the actual backend call in redux reducer or should I make backend call in my component onInit method and add the data to redux state later on? Which one is the right way to do? I heard that redux reducer should be pure functions so is doing backend call make the function inpure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not make a backend call in a reducer. [Redux docs say](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions):

> The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action, and returns the next state

And:

> No side effects. No API calls. No mutations. Just a calculation.

Side effects in Redux can be done via [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), or making side-effect calls in plain Redux middleware.

Of those options, redux-thunk is easiest to get started with. It lets you do async/side-effects in the actions.

```js
// store.js
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const myReduxStore = createStore(myRootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

```js
// actions.js
const myAction = (someArg) => {
  return dispatch => {
    myApiCall().then(result => {
      dispatch({ type: 'YAY_SUCCESS', result })
    })
  }
}
```

Then when you dispatch the action

```
dispatch(myAction())
```

The async side-effect will occur after the dispatch call but before the reducer picks up the action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should not make api calls in reducer as they should be pure and free from any side effects.

> Should I make backend call in my component onInit method and add the
>   data to redux state later on?

I would suggest going by this approach.